# Wordpress no longer holding post formatting

Tags: tinymce, formatting

When creating a new post, by entering either manually or pasting from another document, TinyMCE (the default WordPress editor) does not seem to hold any type of formatting. For instance I create a two paragraph entry. When viewing it on the page it will come through as a single chunk of text within `<div class="entry-content">`. It's forcing me to have to revisit posts quite a bit and manually entering paragraph tags `<p>`.

I'm unsure what's causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE - at least, as-configured for WordPress - isn't explicitly designed for copying/pasting of text richly formatted in other word processors.

That said: how are you pasting? Are you simply copy/pasting (i.e. via CTRL-C, CTRL-V; or else via right-clicking and using contextual menu commands), or are you using the "Paste From Word" button on the TinyMCE toolbar?

If you're not using the "Paste From Word" button, please give it a try:

1) On the TinyMCE toolbar, click the "Kitchen Sink" button (last button on the right, on the top row of buttons)
2) Additional rows of buttons will appear
3) On the second row of buttons, click the "Paste From Word" button (the icon is a clipboard with a "Word" icon, "W")

EDIT:

Are you removing the wpautop() filter? Look for something like this in functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

That would definitely cause the line-break issue you're seeing.

Comment: Seems as though it occurs no matter how I insert it. Even when starting a fresh post and pressing enter to create the paragraphs.

Comment: Where are you originally creating/formatting your content? Are you using a word processor (such as MS Word, etc.)? That creates its own potential issues, but is, I think, a separate issue entirely. Are you saying also that when you create original text in the Visual Editor, and then apply formatting to that text, using the TinyMCE formatting toolbar, that formatting isn't retained?

Comment: What I'm saying is that no matter how I input data into the editor it does not retain line breaks. It occurs when I paste from any document type or when I physically create original text in the visual editor. In order to create line breaks I must do it by hand in the html editor.

Comment: What Theme are you using? Are you performing any custom filtering of the $init array passed to TinyMCE, e.g. in your functions.php file?

Comment: It's a custom theme. I only have a few references to init in functions.php I went ahead and removed them all and individually with no results.

Comment: What you would actually be looking for would be references to the 'tiny_mce_before_init' hook.

Comment: And just to clarify: are you having problems with applying formatting style via the TinyMCE toolbar buttons, or is your problem limited to line-break issues?

Comment: My specific problem is related to line breaks. I searched my theme directory and was unable to find anything referring to tiny_mce_before_init.

Comment: Are you removing the wpautop filter? I've edited my answer to show the example code to look for in functions.php.

Comment: Excellent! The WordPress Post Tabs Plugin on line 67 in wordpress-post-tabs.php is what was removing wpautop. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter the same issue and i followed the following post.

http://forums.innovsystems.com/forum/topic/24

The problem is TinyMCE is formating our html. When it formating our HTML it removes br tags and empty paragraph tags